# Using constructor of Friend Class

Tags: c++, friend

I have two classes A and B.  A has declared B as a friend.  In B I would like to instantiate A in method func() (i.e I am trying to instantiate A outside of the constructor of B).  To my suprise this seems to be not allowed in C++.  This is the code:

```
class A {
public:
        friend class B;
        A(int x, int y) {
                x_ = x;
                y_ = y;
        }
protected:
        int x_, y_;
};

class B {
public: 
        B (int z) {
                z_ = z;
        }

        void func () {
                a (3,4);
        }
protected:
        A a;
        int z_
};
```

I get the following errors:

```
friendConstructor.cpp: In constructor ‘B::B(int)’:
friendConstructor.cpp:14:12: error: no matching function for call to ‘A::A()’
friendConstructor.cpp:14:12: note: candidates are:
friendConstructor.cpp:4:2: note: A::A(int, int)
friendConstructor.cpp:4:2: note:   candidate expects 2 arguments, 0 provided
friendConstructor.cpp:1:7: note: A::A(const A&)
friendConstructor.cpp:1:7: note:   candidate expects 1 argument, 0 provided
friendConstructor.cpp: In member function ‘void B::func()’:
friendConstructor.cpp:19:9: error: no match for call to ‘(A) (int, int)’
```

I have a situation where I can't instansiate class A in class B's constructor.  I have to wait for something to happen before I instansiate class A.  If what I am trying to do is impossible in C++.  Can you suggest an alternative?

Comment: Use a (smart) pointer instead?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In `func`, `a` is a member variable, so it's instance was initialized (default constructed since you didn't specify how you wanted it initializing) when your instance of B was constructed. It has to be - it's a part of B.

What you are actually doing is calling overloaded `A::operator()`. The "a(3,4)" syntax only means "construct with these arguments" in a declaration or an initializer list of a constructor.

Your solutions are to add a member function to A to allow you to assign variables or construct a temporary and use assignment.

```
 a = A(3,4);
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to initialize `a` yourself as `A` doesn't contain a default constructor

```
class B {
public: 
        B (int z) : a(3,4) {
                z_ = z;
        }
protected:
        A a;
        int z_;
};
```

Answer (score 0):

As the error says, you are making a function call, you probably want something like:

```
 a = A(3,4);
```

Answer (score 0):

`A` doesn't have a default constructor.  Since there is an instance of `A` in every `B`, the default constructor of `B` calls the default constructor of `A`, which doesn't exist.

Concerning what you are trying to do: as far as I'm aware, member variables should be instantiated as soon as the class instance is created.  Think about it this way - what if you had a different method in `B`, let's call it `func2()`, which accesses `a`.  Should we trust whoever uses your class to simply not use `func2` until they've called `func`?  No - that's not a safe programming practice.  So basically, you should make sure that member variables are instantiated in the constructors.

You may be able to get around this, as @benjymous has pointed out, by using a pointer, or as @kfsone and @dornhege have pointed out, by simply assigning to `a` a new `A` instance (`a = A(3, 4)`).  But again, I would suggest that it's generally preferable to make sure that member variables are instantiated for the lifetime of the class instance.